# How do I remove parentheses around a year in the references using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I have an issue whereby I would like to get the parentheses removed around the year in the following reference, and a period added after the author list.

For example, I would like to change:
"Ambler, Steve and Florian Pelgrin (2010). “Time-consistent control in non-linear models”. In:
Journal of Economic Dynamics and Control 34(10), pp. 2215–2228."

to

"Ambler, Steve and Florian Pelgrin. 2010). “Time-consistent control in non-linear models”. In:
Journal of Economic Dynamics and Control 34(10), pp. 2215–2228."

Here is the relevant code:

```
\begin{document}
...
% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,%
            uniquename=false,%
            backend=bibtex,%
            maxcitenames=1,%
            natbib=true,%
            doi=false,%
            url=false,%
            isbn=false,%
            maxnames=20]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}


\DeclareFieldFormat[]{title}{\MakeCapital{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{day}%
  \clearfield{month}%
  \clearfield{endday}%
  \clearfield{endmonth}%
}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
\setunit{\addspace}
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\blx@unitmark{23sp}
%\makeatother

...
\pdfbookmark{References}{sec:references} \printbibliography
...
\end{document}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Please provide a full MWE.

Comment: Do you want the date changed (in your example) to: `2010).` or to `2010.`?